# Error with MariaDB on php webservice

Tags: php, syntax

I have the next php web service, that is connected to an android app. I'm trying to get the whole info from a table, this table has some other related tables, so i need to pick info from different tables at the same time using the previous query. Well, in fact i have this php code:

```
<?PHP

Class Coord{
public $latitude;
public $longitude;

function __construct($latitude,$longitude){
    $this->latitude = $latitude;
    $this->longitude = $longitude;
}
}
Class Resposta{
public $sResposta;
public $correcta;

function __construct($sResposta,$correcta){
    $this->sResposta = $sResposta;
    $this->correcta = $correcta;
}
}
Class Pregunta{
public $pregunta;
public $respostes;
public $estat;  

function __construct($pregunta,$respostes,$estat){
    $this->pregunta = $pregunta;
    $this->respostes = $respostes;
    $this->estat = $estat;
}
}
Class Ubicacio{
public $nom;
public $provincia;
public $descripcio;
public $visitada;
public $valorada;
public $pregunta;
public $coord;

function __construct($nom,$provincia,$descripcio,$visitada,$valorada,$pregunta,$coord){
    $this->nom = $nom;
    $this->provincia = $provincia;
    $this->descripcio = $descripcio;
    $this->visitada = $visitada;
    $this->valorada = $valorada;
    $this->pregunta = $pregunta;
    $this->coord = $coord;
}
}
Class ContenidoLlistaUbicacions{
public $llistaUbicacions;
}

$hostname_localhost = "whatever";
$database_localhost = "whatever";
$username_localhost = "whatever";
$password_localhost = "whatever";

error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);

$connection=mysql_connect($hostname_localhost,$username_localhost,$password_localhost)
or
trigger_error(my_error(),E_USER_ERROR);

mysql_select_db($database_localhost,$connection);

$query = "SELECT * FROM ubicacions;";
$query_exec = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

$contingut = new ContenidoLlistaUbicacions;
$contingut->llistaUbicacions = array(); 

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_exec)){
//assignem el valor de id_pregunta a una variable
$where = $row['id_pregunta'];
//conseguir las respuestas para cada pregunta de cada ubicación
$queryR = "SELECT * FROM respostes WHERE id_pregunta = $where;";
$query_execR = mysql_query($queryR) or die(mysql_error());
$respostes=array();
//crear las respuestas
while($rowR = mysql_fetch_array($query_exec)){
$respostes = new Resposta($rowR['resposta'],$rowR['correcta']);
}
//agafam la pregunta de la ubicació
$queryP = "SELECT * FROM preguntes WHERE id_pregunta = $where;";
$query_execP = mysql_query($queryP) or die(mysql_error());
$rowP = mysql_fetch_row($query_execP);
$pregunta = new Pregunta($rowP['pregunta'],$respostes,0);
//cream la ubicació
$coord = new Coord($row['latitud'],$row['longitud']);
$ubicacio = new Ubicacio($row['nom_ubicacio'],$row['provincia_pertany'],$row['descripcio'],$row['num_visites'],$row['suma_valoracio'],$coord);
$contingut->llistaUbicacions=$ubicacio;
}
echo json_encode($contingut);
?>
```

And im getting the next error:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

I've checked blank spaces, parentheses, the ; on the sql queries, almost everything i've found at the net... Im getting mad, thx guys!

Comment: I'm hoping those aren't your real DB credentials for a start? Next, mysql_* functions are deprecated and should not be used if at all possible. Finally, try dumping your SQL queries I'm wondering if $where is empty. Finally finally, Shouldn't your second mysql_fetch_array be using $query_execR?

Comment: They where my credentials >.<.. really stupid by my part. In any case, i just changed them! I know i have to change those deprecated functions, but its just for a class project, nothing 2 serious...  Ill change that fetch and try, just posted an old php file! thx for the fast answer!

Comment: Done, dont know why my Database was empty, lucky me I had a security copy! Thx very much Jon!